# Reprocess SSAS tabular cube after failure

Tags: sql, ssas, ssas-tabular

So we process the SSAS tabular cubes every night and the other night the processing of the cube failed. Now what I want to do is implement a system that would trigger an automatic reprocess after failure.

Is there a way to do that in SSAS Tabular?

Comment: Nothing built into SSAS will do this. Where do you schedule or automate the processing? Detect an error there and retry on error.

Comment: Right now we have an SSIS package that does that through sql server job agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing built into SSAS will automatically restart processing on error.

In SQL Agent, the Job Step Properties dialog has an Advanced tab with a Retry Attempts property. If you change that to 1, then it will automatically retry the step (the SSIS package) if it fails.

Comment: ok. So I was wrong earlier when I said SQL Agent. Seems like they recently changed it to using Informatica to call SSIS packages. And I dont have any knowledge of Informatica at all. Is there a property I can change in Informatica?

Comment: I don't know Informatica either. You can certainly do automatic retries in SSIS by looping until successful. I assume the same is possible in Informatica. You might open a new question focused on retries in Informatica if that's the direction you want to go.

Comment: For others who find this thread in the future the Informatica focused thread is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644420/reprocess-tabular-cubes-after-failure-using-informatica

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in ssis then have a failure constraint looping back to the processing task?

The problem would be if you  Have a data error that needs to be fixed.