# Reprocess tabular cubes after failure using Informatica

Tags: sql, ssis, ssas, informatica, ssas-tabular

So we process the SSAS tabular cubes every night and the other night the processing of the cube failed. Now what I want to do is implement a system that would trigger an automatic reprocess after failure.

Is there a way to do that in SSAS Tabular? If not, then can I do it using Informatica. Because as of now we call SSIS packages using Informatica to process the cubes.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to do it in Informatica. In SQL Server, there is a setting on the SQL Agent job for number of retries and amount of time to wait between retries. There should be something similar in Informatica.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reprocess SSAS tabular cube after failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623475/reprocess-ssas-tabular-cube-after-failure)